# How do I use JavaScript to grow an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple web application with which a user may author a message with attached files.

[multiple html file inputs with javascript link http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/4474/attachments.gif](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/4474/attachments.gif)

That "attach additional files" link does not yet work.  It should add an additional file input control to the form each time it's clicked.

I need a JavaScript method *addanotherfileinput()* to replace the clicked anchor:

```
        <a href="#" id="attachlink" onclick="addanotherfileinput">attach additional files</a>
```

With this new table row, file input, and anchor:

```
        <input type="file" name="Attachment1" id="Attachment1" class="textinput" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="attachlink" onclick="addanotherfileinput">attach additional files</a>
```

And also increment the number: Attachment2, Attachment3, Attachment4, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the DOM to dynamically insert the file inputs

```
var myTd = /* Get the td from the dom */

var myFile = document.createElement('INPUT');
myFile.type = 'file'
myFile.name = 'files' + i; // i is a var stored somewhere
i++;

myTd.appendChild(myFile);
```

OR you can use this

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/uploader/uploader-simple-button.html

Comment: Note: I am putting all the file inptus in one TD, in your case you may want to make a whole new row, but doing that is about the same as what I am doing up here... its just adding a few more dom elements to the document.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way, but I did this client side by creating a set of HTML form elements and then hiding/showing the rows using JavaScript to update the CSS class.

EDIT: I'll leave this here as an alternate method but I like the idea of adding INPUT elements through the DOM better.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to *replace* the anchor, just insert something in front of it.

I use [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) for things like this, because it irons out a lot of browser inconsistencies, particularly around forms and tables.

Using Prototype, it would look something like this:

```
function insertFileField(element, index) {
    element.insert({
        before: "<input type='file' name='Attachment" + index + " class='textinput'>"
    });
}

// And where you're hooking up your `a` element (`onclick` is very outdated,
// best to use unubtrustive JavaScript)
$('attachlink').observe('click', function(event) {
    event.stop();
    insertFileField(this, this.up('form').select('input[type=file]').length + 1);
});
```

...the bit at the end finds the form containing the link, finds out how many `input`s of type `file` there are, and adds one for the index.

There are other ways as well, via the `Element` constructor provided by Prototype, but text works quite well (in fact, it's usually much faster).

It would be similar, though slightly different, with jQuery, MooTools, YUI, Glow, or any of the several other JavaScript frameworks.