# How do I use jQuery to grow an HTML form?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a simple web application with which a user may author a message with attached files.

[multiple HTML file inputs with jQuery link http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/4474/attachments.gif](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/4474/attachments.gif)

That "attach another file" link does not yet work.  When clicked, it should add an additional table row and file input control to the form.

```
<tr id="fileinput0">
    <td>Attachments</td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="Attachment0" id="Attachment0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="fileinput1">
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="Attachment1" id="Attachment1" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="addinput">
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">attach another file</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It should also increment the number: fileinput2, Attachment2; fileinput3, Attachment3; etc.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Related question: How do I use JavaScript to grow an HTML form?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330035/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-grow-an-html-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved it around so it was all within a single table row:

```
<tr>
    <td>Attachments (<a id="addinput" href="#">add</a>)</td>
    <td id="fileinputs">
        <input type="file" name="Attachment0" id="Attachment0" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And used this jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var num = 0;
        $("#addinput").click(function() {
            num++;
            $("#fileinputs").append("<br /><input type=\"file\" name=\"Attachment" + num + "\" id=\"Attachment" + num + "\" />");
        });
    });
</script>
```

It now looks like this:

[multiple HTML file inputs with jQuery link http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/4474/attachments.gif](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/4474/attachments.gif)

Comment: Should that link be "add" or "more"?  Or, should I handle some onchange event and have no such link at all?

Answer (score 4):

This'll get you most of the way there.

```
var row = $('table tr:last').clone();
$(row).attr('id', 'new_ID');
$('input', row).attr('id', 'new_ID_for_input');
$('table').append(row);
```

Comment: Good idea with clone, but `append` should be exchanged for `after`.

Comment: @Joel Why? After would place the row after (and thus outside!) the table. Append places it within the table, as a table row should be.

Comment: But append puts it as the last element in the table, where you really want to put it after the previous upload row, and before the addinput row. You're selector would have to change to `'table tr#lastrowid'`. I also just noticed that you are cloning the last row, when you want to clone the second-to-last row (or last input row).

Comment: I'd actually advise pulling 'attach another file' out of the table to make things easier, but you're correct, my quickie solution doesn't account for that yet.

Comment: Oops, I upvoted a comment.  Doesn't seem I can un-upvote it???  I think using something like $(this).parent('tr').before(row); would work.  Personally I would look at the onchange event (or whatever it is) and not have a button at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the HTML you want to append to the form and insert it into the appropriate container using [jQuery.append()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content).

Sometimes what I'll do is keep a TBODY in my form table and give that TBODY and ID so I can reference it via jQuery to append extra rows/cells/form inputs.

Comment: Technically `append` will stick it on the end, whereas I think the OP wants it in the middle somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this.

```
inputNum = 2;

function GrowTable()
{
    var input = $("<tr id=\"fileinput" + inputNum + "\">
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type=\"file\" name=\"Attachment" + inputNum + "\" id=\"Attachment" + inputNum + "\" />
        </td>
    </tr>");

    input.insertAfter("#fileinput" + (inputNum - 1));

    inputNum++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a counter might help, something like

```
$('form').append("<tr id=\"fileinput" + i + "\"><td></td><td><input type=\"file\" /></td></tr>");
```